# How to use Authentication on my login Controller

Tags: laravel

i set code to auth the admin only can login but the code look like ignored by login controller

i take code from laravel documentation and use on my loginController

```
   public function authenticate()
    {
      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'admin' => 1])) {
        return redirect()->intended('home');
      } else {
        return redirect()->route('login');
      }
    }
```

i wan to login if my column admin is ==1  else return b to login and why the controller ignore the authenticate ?

Comment: Try changing method name from authenticate to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check `admin => 1` in auth attempt. Try with this

```php
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

 if (Auth::User()->admin == '1') {

        return redirect()->intended('home');
     } else {

       return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```